# Add to a List from two Classes in C#

Tags: c#

I have a list in one class. And I need to populate the list from another class. Then I need to access the list one or two other classes. I don't want to use static list. How is this done in C#. I tried my best. But not successful. Can anybody show example?.

Comment: use a getter/setter (i.e. a Property in c#)?

Comment: How are the classes related? Can you use inheritance? We really need much more details in order to help.

Comment: Can you post the definitions of your classes and list so we have a better idea of what you need?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by not using a static list?

Answer (score 3):

use get I would suggest

This is where the list is

```
class A
{

    private list<Objects> myList = new list<Objects>();

    public list<Objects> getList()
    {
        return myList;
    }
}
```

This is where you want to use it

```
class B
{
    private list<Objects> myNewList = new list<Objects>();
    A a = new A();

    public void setList()
    {
        myNewList = a.getlist();
    }
}
```

Something like this. Remember same namespace for classes to know each other, if in different files

Comment: this looks a lot like `java`. Are you sure you don't want to use a `property` instead?

Comment: If he just wants to get, I think this is fine. But if he also wants to set, a property would be better yes

Comment: uhm.. `public List<object> myList { get { ... } private set { ... } }`

Comment: Watch out, OP wants to set the list from another class, `private set` would prevent it.

Comment: This will still work, but what you write is also true and probably better in general for C#. Guess I am still more of a C++ guy :)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for a public property.

```
// I'm assuming a List of strings, fix accordingly
public class A
{
    //Not autoimplemented to ensure it's always initialized
    private List<string> items = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set { items = value; }
    }
}

public class AnyoneElse
{
     void someMethod()
     {
         A someVar = new A();

         someVar.Items.Add("This was added from outside");

         MessageBox.Show(someVar.Items.First());
     }
}
```

Access modifiers should be tweaked appropriately (they depend on your namespace structure, mostly. Also, are the class and the consumers in the same assembly or not ? Anyway, the point should be clear enough).

Comment: changed to use the variable instead of the type.

Comment: Ah you're right, I missed that one before posting.

Comment: still upvoted, a property is the way to go here

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example of what you need

```
public class YourOriginalClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The list you want to access
    /// </summary>
    public List<YourType> YourList { 
       get; 
       set; 
    }
}

// Here another class where you can use the list
public class YourSecondClass
{
    public void EditMyList()
    {
       YourOriginalClass test = new YourOriginalClass();
       test.YourList = new List<YourType>();
       // then you can populate it
    }
}
```

Comment: I resolved my problem by using inheritance. Even I learnt that from other pages of this site. I thank you everyone. I will experiment with the suggestions here. Right now I am learning a little bit of Regular Expressions. Fascinating! Thank you everyone.